# Is there anyway to show all results in a view initially, but only show 1 result after user sets an exposed filter?

Tags: views

I need to be able to show all results of my view initially but then only show 1 result after the user selects their options form the exposed filters.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this seems like a really odd thing to want to do! How would you narrow it down to a single result if more than one matches the filter?

Anyway,  you should be able to use this hook:
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7

If you check for the existence of filter values, you can then apply a "LIMIT 1" to the query.

Comment: It isn't an odd request when you know the actual use-case. It's a proximity search box that allows user to see which constituency zone they are in on a map. There is only one possible answer. However they still need to see all of the zones on the map before filtering.

Comment: okay! That becomes much easier!  I assume that your filters would mean they'd only end up with 1 result?